# Entity Framework Fluent API Relationship Syntax

Tags: entity-framework

Code from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620

Given these EF classes:

```
public class Instructor 
{ 
    public Instructor() 
    { 
        this.Courses = new List<Course>(); 
    } 

    // Primary key 
    public int InstructorID { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public System.DateTime HireDate { get; set; } 

    // Navigation properties 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; private set; } 
} 

public class OfficeAssignment 
{ 
    // Specifying InstructorID as a primary 
    [Key()] 
    public Int32 InstructorID { get; set; } 

    public string Location { get; set; } 

    // When the Entity Framework sees Timestamp attribute 
    // it configures ConcurrencyCheck and DatabaseGeneratedPattern=Computed. 
    [Timestamp] 
    public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; } 

    // Navigation property 
    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; } 
}
```

And given this fluent API code example:

```
   // Configure the primary key for the OfficeAssignment 
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
    .HasKey(t => t.InstructorID); 

// Map one-to-zero or one relationship 
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor) 
    .WithOptional(t => t.OfficeAssignment); // Confused here
```

And knowing that `WithOptional` method has this definition in MSDN:

```
RequiredNavigationPropertyConfiguration<TEntityType, TTargetEntityType>.WithOptional Method (Expression<Func<TTargetEntityType, TEntityType>>)
```

How is that possible to have `t => t.OfficeAssignment` where t is of type `Instructor`, and does not have a property named `OfficeAssignment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article miss this property on `Instructor` class.

```
public class Instructor 
{ 
    public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

Or remove the lambda expression.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Instructor) 
    .WithOptional();
```